# Rails nested model get field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my app I have such model structure:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization_type
  has_many :organization_type_links, :dependent => :destroy
end

class OrganizationType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  has_many :organization_type_links
end

class OrganizationTypeLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :organization_type
end
```

So OrganizationTypeLink is a linking table, and how could I fetch via it OrganizationType.t_name?

Like I write:

= @organization.organization_type_links.t_name

Is it real? And how to do it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@organization.organization_type_links` is an array. Try the following to call `t_name` method on `organization_type`:

```
@organization.organization_type_links.collect{|link| link.organization_type.t_name}
```

This returns an array of whatever t_name returns.

Comment: just tht this is array... how to style it for view without [ ] ?

Comment: something like `[1,2,3,4].to_sentence(:last_word_connector => " and ")` ? (returns  "1, 2, 3 and 4")

Comment: or maybe `[1,2,3,4].join(", ") # => "1, 2, 3, 4"`?